# How to setup some .NET Core Dependency Injection for a class where constructor includes an HttpClient and some strings?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Given the following .NET Core 2.2 class definition:

```
public class MyService : ISomeService
{
    public MyService(string apiKey, HttpClient httpClient) { ... } 
}
```

how do I setup the DI to use `HttpClientFactory` and to use this concrete instance when an ISomeService is constructor-injected to *other* classes? E.g.

```
services.AddHttpClient<ISomeService, MyService>();
services.AddSingleton<ISomeService, MyService>(
    sp => new MyService("some api key from config", sp.GetService<??????????>() );
```

Comment: Lets assume I cannot modify `MyService`. Yes, I could create a parent class that inherits this - but for argument's sake, lets again so no to that.

Comment: Inject IHttpClientFactory instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promote your `apiKey` configuration value to a Parameter Object:

```
public sealed class MyServiceConfiguration
{
    public readonly string ApiKey;

    public MyServiceConfiguration(string apiKey)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey)) throw new ArgumentException(...);
        this.ApiKey = apiKey;
    }
}
```

And change your `MyService` constructor to:

```
public MyService(MyServiceConfiguration config, HttpClient httpClient)
```

The new `MyServiceConfiguration` can be easily registered as follows:

```
services.AddSingleton(new MyServiceConfiguration("some api key from config"));
```

Please be warned about the use of the injection of `HttpClient` into `Singleton` consumers. As described [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore), [here](https://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html), and [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), numerous problems can occur when `HttpClient` instances are reused for the duration of the application, which will use with your current configuration. When you register `MyService` as a `Singleton`, `HttpClient` will become a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Instead, register your `MyService` as `Scoped`. [Ideally](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/924), ASP.NET Core should be able to detect this Captive Dependency for you, but in its current implementation (v2.2) it does not do so, which means you're better off protecting yourself by making your direct consumer `Scoped` (and documenting clearly why this is, to prevent the next developer from screwing things up again).

Comment: How about changing it to `services.AddSingleton(sp => new MSC("api key"));` <-- so that class is disposed by the system and not require manually to be disposed of? (trying to avoid creating _any_ objects that require disposable)

Comment: What dispose logic could that Parameter Object with configuration values possibly have?

Comment: In that specific case I would say: don't worry about it :)